# Conditional Formatting is not allowing me to run my Code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying sumbycolor formula but it's not working as conditional formatting is applied inside the sheet.

I found this line to be added inside Code

```
 wRes.Cells(ColIndex, cS).FormatConditions.Delete
```

But I don't know how to adjust it inside my Code. Someone please help. Thanks

Code:

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
    Dim cSum As Double
    Dim ColIndex As Integer
    ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each cl In rRange
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
            cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
        End If
    Next cl
    SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```

---

Sheet:

[image: Sheet]

Comment: Do you wish to remove conditional formatting from the range?

Comment: @QHarr. No. I just want that it should not reflect inside my User Defined Formula "sumbycolor"

Comment: Please explain a little more about what not working means in this context.

Comment: I am writing this Formula: =SumByColor(G11,G11:G20)+SumByColor(G11,H11:H20)+SumByColor(G11,J11:J20)+SumByColor(G11,K11:K20)+SumByColor(G11,L11:L20)

Comment: But answer is coming wrong as Cells are highlighted via Conditional Formatting and not Manually

Comment: You probably want to change `ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex` into `ColIndex = CellColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.Colorindex` and also `cl.Interior.ColorIndex` into `cl.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`

Comment: @JvdV No. It is giving Error. Error: #Value

Comment: @JvdV It is still giving Error

Comment: Well, just found out `.DisplayFormat` is not supported in UDF :(. Bad luck